# Which instances give which reputation?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have noticed from my brief periods in the new dungeon instances that the Mists of Pandaria expansion has added to WoW, that reputation no longer trickles in as you kill trash enemies but that you still get small amounts of faction reputation from particular actions.

Which instances in Mists of Pandaria gives reputation for which factions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any of the instances provide reputation for killing enemies within them, there may be experience from some of the quests within the instances though.

It is possible to get a tabard to represent the Pandaren faction for Alliance/Horde, sold by a panda next to the portal for Pandaria in both Stormwind and Orgrimmar.